# In The Qur'an is there an explanation of how "Existence" or "The Universe" began like in Genesis of The Bible?

Tags: quran, allah, creation, bible, scripture

Here's the wiki link which describes it. [Genesis Creation Narrative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_creation_narrative).

I ask because I believe I have figured out how it began and it shows that the first 9 verses of The Bible are correct but said in a code-like way. So I was wondering if The Qur'an had a clearer less code-like explanation of the beginning of everything. My site where I believe I have figured out how it all started is at http://life.mzzhost.com/text.pdf

So, please try to answer the title which asks it in a clear way.

Hopefully you forgive any errors I might have made in asking this question.

Edit: The site I linked appears not to be working so email me for the .pdf file at paul.obrien.hunter@outlook.com. I tried other ways to share the file but they do not work as I am on a bad phone.

Comment: "Have not those who disbelieve known that the heavens and the earth were joined together as one united piece, then We parted them? And We have made from water every living thing. Will they not then believe?? " sura Al-Anbiya , the big-bang theory :)

Comment: Remember the bible also contains the word of God so you can just take the narrative from the Bible.  Also your link is broken. Please fix it.

Comment: @ZeRubeus that verse is out of context. Also the heavens and earth were never "one" piece. The earth came much much later. So that verse must be interpreted differently.